# /var and /var/www permissions

Tags: apache

The mode for both these directories is 755. I'd like to restrict permissions to 754. But if I do so, I'm thinking the apache www-data instance won't be able to access the directories to serve the contained files.

1. Is there a canonical mode for these directories. 2. What's a good way to provide the apache instance access: through creating some sort of group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the chmod for `/var`as this should remain default.

Apache runs on the usergroup www-data so `/var/www` should have the owner has www-data and not root, if this is the case then 754 is absolutely fine.

*This may help:*

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/www
chmod -R 754 /var/www
```

Normally this is set-up for you if you used an installer such as apt-get when installing Apache or nginx.